# I just don't get the C++ Pointer/Reference system

Tags: c++

I've never had problems with references as in Python (implicit) or PHP (explicit &). In PHP you write `$p = &$myvar;` and you have `$p` as a reference pointing to `$myVar`.

So I know in C++ you can do this:

```
void setToSomething( int& var )
{
 var = 123;
}
int myInt;
setToSomething( myInt );
```

- myInt is now 123, why?

Doesn't & mean "memory address of" x in C++? What do I do then if var is only the address to `myInt` and not a pointer?

```
void setToSomething( int* var )
{
 *var = 123;
}
int myInt;
int* myIntPtr = &myInt;
setToSomething( myIntPtr );
```

- Does the above work as expected?

I don't understand the difference between * and & in C++ fully. They tell you & is used to get the address of a variable, but why does that help you in functions etc. Like in the first example?

Comment: &a - adders of a; 
(*a) - stuff lays in the memory address which lays in a (so a type is int*\float*\type*), so (*(&a)) = a, probably. (I'm not sure - that's how I understand that, that's why I write it in as comment).

Comment: wha.. var* = 123; ???? thats not right is it.

Comment: I meant '*a'. It seemed to be as style.

Comment: It has name because you can put adress of int variable into variable of type 'adress of variable of type int'.

Comment: Yeah, and it should be '(*var)' there.

Comment: @Minner: How about you remove those confusing 4 comments and replace them with a single one that says exactly what you meant?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the first example, `&` is used to declare a reference type.
It's not the same thing as the `&` operator which is used to get an object's address.

You can view a reference type as a type which uses under the covers a pointer which can never be `NULL`.

Comment: So why use pointers when I can have reference types everywhere?

Comment: @gnm: You can do things, evil things, with pointers that you can't with references. Sometimes those are necessary.

Comment: @gnm in c/c++ pointers are often used in the performance vs safety tradeoffs. Especially in image manipulation, using (wisely) pointers will give you the ultimate performance

Comment: @gnm: The advantage of pointers over references is that you can later reset them to point to some other object. That makes them more flexible. The advantage of references over pointers is that they cannot be reset to point to any other object than the one they were initialized with. Since this includes that they cannot (well, it's harder to have them) point to a no longer existing object, that makes them safer.

Comment: @Vivek: I don't see how using pointers would give you a speed advantage over references.

Comment: @sbi: I agree.  Since references are almost certainly implemented as pointers by the compiler, the exact same code should be output by the compiler for both the reference andf the pointer version.

Comment: @sbi is perfectly right about one advantage of pointers. Here's another: You can have several levels of indirection, i. e. pointers to pointers. That's not possible with references (you can't take the address of a reference, only of the thing the reference points to). Of course, several levels of indirection tend to knot brains, so they should be used sparingly, however, there are circumstances where they are *really* handy. Searching and removing entries from a linked list, for example.

Answer (score 29):

> Doesn't & mean "memory address of" x in C++?

---

Short answer: That depends.

---

Longer answer: The ***unary prefix operator `&`***, when applied to an object, indeed yields the ***address*** of the object: `&obj`. There is, however, also the ***type modifier `&`***, which, when applied to a type, will modify it to be a ***reference type***: `int&`.

The same applies to `*`: When used as a ***unary prefix operator***, it will ***dereference*** a pointer: `*ptr`. When used as a ***type modifier***, it will modify the type to be a ***pointer***: `int*`.

It's not helpful either that ***type modifiers apply to the variable that is declared***. For example, this

```
int *p, **pp, i, &r = i;
```

defines an `int` pointer, a pointer to a pointer to an `int`, a vanilla `int`, and an `int` reference. (The latter is immediately initialized, because you cannot have an uninitialized reference.) Note that the ***type modifiers syntactically belong to the declared variable*** whose type they are modifying, not to the declared variable's type. Nevertheless, type modifiers (`*` and `&`) modify the *type* of the variable.
In the following case, however, with `pp` and `i` presumed to be variables that have already been declared

```
*pp = &i;
```

`*` and `&` are unary prefix operators dereferencing `pp` and yielding the address of `i`.

(In the same vein, the ***type modifier `[]`*** when applied to a variable that's being declared, will modify the variable's type to an array, while the ***binary infix operator `[]`***, when applied to an object of array type will access one of its sub-objects.)

---

To complicate things even further, besides the *type modifiers* and the *unary prefix operators* `&` and `*`, there are also the ***binary infix operators*** `&` and `*`, meaning "bitwise AND" and "multiplication". And to add insult to injury, in C++ you can ***[overload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)*** both the *unary prefix* and the *binary infix* variants of these operators (and the *binary infix* `[]`) for user-defined types and be completely free as to their semantics.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the &-operator serves two purposes as posted above.

the first purpose is dereference, which is used like this:

```
int i = 123; //declare an integer variable named i with the value of 123
int *pI = &i; //declare an pointer-to-integer 
              //variable name pI pointing to the memory address of i
```

The &-operator is used in the meaning 'give me the memory address of'

the second purpose is to emulate call-by-reference (which c does not have natively)

a declaration like

```
void foo(int& theInt)
{
  theInt = 123;
}
```

will make the function foo accept an int parameter, to which any modification during the execution of foo is passed back.

Without the &-operator, modifications to theInt would be made in the foo's scope only and discarded once the function terminates.

Answer (score 1):

`&` is used in functions when you need to return more than one variable value unlike the `return` statement which returns a single variable.

Comment: It also wasn't my question but still, great answer

Answer (score 0):

In the second example it should be

```
*var = 123
```

Think of the ampersand in the argument declaration as the `var` keyword in Pascal, it's used to specify that the variable will be updated if changed. I'm not sure if the C++ semantics specify that it will be passed always by reference or it could be done via a pass by value and copy on return if it's more efficient for a given case...