# Type Declaration - Pointer Asterisk Position

Tags: c++, pointers

in C++, the following means "allocate memory for an int pointer":

```
int* number;
```

So, the asterisk is part of the variable type; without it, that would mean "allocate memory for an int".

Then, wouldn't it make more sense if the following meant "allocate memory for two int pointers"?

```
int* number1, number2;
```

Comment: [Stroustrup's answer](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#whitespace) for the very same question.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Stroustrup was asked this and he said (paraphrasing)

> - if you think more C-ish you will say **int *a** and **Employee *pE**
>     (so in your head you're thinking "the content of **a** is an integer")
> - if you think more C++-ish you will say **int* a** and **Employee* pE**
>     (so in your head it's "**a** is an integer pointer")
>
> You can think however you like, as long as you never declare two
>   pointers on the same line.

Works for me. I'm an `Employee* pE` kind of person, but I'm married to an `Employee *pE` kind of person - my advice would be not to get too worked up about it.

Answer (score 31):

Actually the asterisk is attached to the variable (a convention inherited from C), so

```
int * number1, number2;
```

declares `number1` as a pointer to `int` (i.e. `*number1` is an `int`), and `number2` as an `int`.

The spacing has no effect on how the `number`'s are typed. It just serves as a token separator. All of the following are the same to compiler, because the spaces will be stripped after parsing.

```
int *a;
int*a;
int* a;
int * a;
int/**a***/*/*a***/a;
```

Use

```
int* number1, *number2;
```

to create two pointers, or even better, split it into multiple declarations to avoid confusion.

```
int* number1;
int* number2;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not asking how I should write it. I'm questioning why the compiler is designed that way. What is the thing that makes this syntax more logical.

Comment: @sahs: There is no good reason it is the way it is except for "it's always been this way". This isn't all that logical, it's _historical_ instead. C, from which we inherited this declaration syntax is 40 years old and well predates much of what is considered good language design nowadays.

Comment: Awesome!!! Its solved my 10000 years old confusion. But G, why people often mix pointers and non pointers...

Answer (score 21):

You are oversimplifying the structure of C++ declaration (even though the points you make are perfectly logical). Only at the first sight it might seem that C++ declaration consists of type name and a sequence of comma separated entity names, but in reality in C++ (as well as in C) declaration actually consists of type name and sequence of *declarators*. The full type information for an entity you declare is split between *two* separate locations and portion of it is actually a part of its declarator. It is just the way it is in C++. In order to better reflect the actual structure of the declaration (as seen by the language), it might be a good idea to format declarations as

```
int *a, *b;
```

i.e. explicitly group `*`s with the entity names, not with the type name. (But in the end it is a matter of personal preference.)

As for why it is designed that that way in the language, as you ask in one of the comments... As you know, the parts of the declaration syntax that describe the type of the entity being declared can appear on the left-hand side of the name (like `*` and `&`) as well as on its right-hand side (like `()` and `[]`) as in

```
int *f(), (&g)[5], h[2][2];
```

For the bits that appear on the right it is simply impossible to do it in any other way. They have no choice but to be grouped with the entity name, not with the type name. One might ask further why the above declarations are not done in C++ as

```
int *() f;
int (&)[5] g;
int [2][2] h;
```

(i.e. everything type-related appears on the left-hand side in a compact group)... Well, the answer to this question is just that it is the way it is in C++. The approach is inherited from C and there the "declaration must resemble the use" is often quoted as the rationale.

P.S. Another thing to remember (and what is often interpreted incorrectly) is that qualifiers adjacent to the type name in the declaration are part of the common *type*, not a part of the first individual declarator. For example

```
int const *a, *b;
```

declares `const int *a` and `const int *b`, not `int *b` as some might mistakingly believe. For this reason I personally prefer to use  the more logical

```
const int *a, *b;
```

ordering (even though at the same time I prefer to group `*` with the name, not with the type).

Comment: It seems more logical that you group `*`, `&`, `()` and `[]` with the name as they describe about _that_ variable although they modify its type but not the type of all other variables in the same line; likewise qualifiers are associated to all variables declared in that line and thus commong so prepending them with type seems correct. I've been doing this without thinking about the rationale, now I know, so I'll continue to stick with it, even at the risk of someone judging me as a C programmer masquerading as a C++ programmer.

Comment: Marshall Cline uses sarcasm in answering a [similar FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/void-in-param-list.html) _(see towards the end)_ to note such prejudices aren't right.

Answer (score 8):

This is just one of the many irregularities of C's declaration syntax. The type modifier `*` is part of the type, yet syntactically it belongs to the identifier that's declared.
The same is true for `&` and `[]`, BTW.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2667476/183120) for what `*` does besides modifying a type.

Comment: This is not an irregularity of C syntax. This is part of the regular syntax of declaration follows use.
This answer is based on the misunderstanding of C syntax that declarations look like: `<type> <name>`. This isn't how C declaration syntax works, and if you think that you will be repeatedly confused and find irregularities.

Comment: @Peaker: I learned to dislike C's declaration syntax around 1992. I first earned money writing C++ code (employing C's declaration syntax) 20 years ago. However, the facts that, by habit and regular use more than two decades, I can understand (most of) it immediately, and that I love C++ do not prevent me from recognizing the declaration syntax as an utter failure, which can only be excused by its enormous antiquity. You, too, should learn to distinguish between the bad you are used to through constant exposure and the good that'd be recognized immediately. Just keep learning!

Answer (score 3):

No,

```
int* number1, number2;
```

Declares `number1` as a pointer to `int`, and `number2` as an `int`. Personally, I also prefer attaching the asterisk to the type, which suffers from exactly the gotcha you bring up in this question, so I would declare two pointers as follows:

```
int* number1;
int* number2;
```