# C - initialization of pointers, asterisk position

Tags: c

What is the most proper way to place asterisk? Why?

```
1)    type*     var;
2)    type      *var;
```

Comment: You forgot `type   *   var`.

Comment: Yet Another duplicate of [What's your preferred pointer declaration style, and why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377164/whats-your-preferred-pointer-declaration-style-and-why), [Type Declaration - Pointer Asterisk Position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704167/type-declaration-pointer-asterisk-position), ...

Comment: @pmg there is also `typedef type* typePTR`

Comment: Voted to close.  Regardless of style, it will *always* be parsed as `type (*var);`.

Comment: The duplicate post is gone so I think this post should be re-opened... unless there is another exact duplicate...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704167/type-declaration-pointer-asterisk-position

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It does not matter as far as you are declaring only one pointer. It is usually writen like in the second example (in the code I usually read/write) but for the compiler it's the same.

The trouble can come out if you are declaring more than one pointer. For example, this is not declaring two pointer, instead it declares one pointer and one var of type type.

```
type* var1, var2;
```

You need to do instead:

```
type* var1, *var2;
```

I prefer to use the * by the var always.

Answer (score 8):

Pointer is the type, and I think it makes most sense to group the type information:

```
int* foo;
```

This can lead to confusion if several variables are defined on the same line:

```
int* foo, bar;  // foo will be int*, bar will be int
```

The solution to this is, never declare several variables on the same line. Something that [Code Complete](http://cc2e.com/) advocates, anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Both work. I'd argue that #1 is clearer in *general*, but misleading in C and can lead to errors, e.g.:

```
type* var1, var2;

// This actually means:

type *var1;
type var2;
```

So I'd say that #2 is more idiomatic in C and therefore recommended, especially if you are not the only programmer working on the code (unless, of course, you all agree on a style).

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, both work fine, and the wrong one actually has the advantage of syntactic economy.

The way I look at it, a declaration consists of **type** followed by the **variable**.

```
<type> <variable>;

int   ii;
int* pii;
```

So, if you take away the **variable**, what remains is the **type**. Which is **int** and **int*** above. The compiler treats **int*** as a type internally (which is **pointer to an int**).

C, unfortunately, does not support this syntax seamlessly. When declaring multiple variables of the same type, you should be able to do this:

```
<type> <variable>, <variable>, <variable>;
```

which you cannot with a pointer type:

```
int* ii1, ii2, ii3;
```

declares ii1 of type **int*** and the rest of type **int**. To avoid this, I make it a habit of declaring only one variable per line.

Answer (score 2):

I've heard it argued that technically the * is a modifier to the variable,
and this is evidenced by the need to use * multiple times in multi variable
declarations
eg. int *p, *q, *r;

However I like to think of it as a modifier to the base type because that
is what appears in prototypes.
eg. void func(int*);

.PMCD.

PS. I know I haven't helped your problem :)

Comment: I never write `int*` (without space) in prototypes unless I'm hitting column 80. IMO `int *` (with space) is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The second mode is correct. The other mode are not so clear for a novice programmer.
The form int* variable  is usually discouraged

Comment: Why is the other mode not so clear?

Comment: when you use int* foo, bar not everybody understand that the variable bar is not a integer pointer

Answer (score 1):

That would rather be a coder's preference.

For me, I declare pointers by:

```
int * var1, var2;
```

Wherein `var1` is a pointer, and `var2` is not. If you want to declare multiple pointers in a line:

```
int * var1, * var2;
```

And of course, using the other ways are valid.

Answer (score 1):

Declaration semantics follow expression semantics (specifically operator precedence) and I find more complex declarations easier to read using the second style.

You can think of

```
int *foo;
```

declaring the type of the expression `*foo` (ie indirection operator applied to `foo`) to be `int` instead of `foo` being declared to be of type `int *`.

Whatever convention you choose, just try to be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single "most proper place".

Usually it is the place the rest of the code uses.

If you're writing your own code from the beginning and can choose your own convention: choose your own convention and stick with it.

If you choose something other than `type * var` you will meet 'awkward' situations:

```
/* write these with another style */
int * var;
int const * var;
int * restrict var;
```

<sub>PS. It shouldn't matter, but I usually use `type *var;`</sub>