# What's the difference between these forms of pointer declarations?

Tags: c, pointers, declaration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C - initialization of pointers, asterisk position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203009/c-initialization-of-pointers-asterisk-position)

What is the difference between these declarations:

```
char* str;
```

and

```
char *str;
```

Is there a difference at all?

Another example:

```
   char* str; 
   struct StrStackLink *next;
```

Are both `str` and `next` pointers or is there any significance in the placement of the star?

Comment: Also similiar, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704167/type-declaration-pointer-asterisk-position, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660633/declaring-pointers-asterisk-on-the-left-or-right-of-the-space-between-the-type, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704167/type-declaration-pointer-asterisk-position

Comment: downvoted: do some research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference - both declare a pointer to a char.  There is a difference when you declare multiple variables on the same line however

```
char* str1, str2;
```

declares `str1` to be a pointer and `str2` to be a char, while

```
char *str1, *str2;
```

declares two char pointers

Comment: +1 for pointing out the unintuitive nature of the multiple declaration.

Answer (score 2):

All of the char pointer declaration you wrote are equivalent.
The placement of the star does change anything.

A case where it can be confusing is the following declaration

```
char* a, b;
```

Here, you declare a, a pointer to `char`, and b, a `char`. So I would recommand to collapse the star with the variable name, for clarity sake.

```
char *a, b;
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope, no difference at all. Just a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no difference, but notation `char *str` is better, because you know that `str` is a pointer.

For example a declaration `char *str1,str2` means that `str1` is a pointer, but `str2` is a char.  A declaration `char* str1,str2` means the same thing, but it's confussing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference.

Do you have any evidence that make you think that way?

You can also declare it this way:

```
char * p;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not difference at all

both `char *str` and `char* str` are same, even

`char    *   str;` is also the same.

space doesn't effect this and `*` always goes with the identifier name.

Yes for 2nd question both `next` and `str` are pointers.

In the case below,

`char *str,s;` here `str` is `pointer` while `s` is only `char`.
If you want to make both as pointer put `*`before each identifier.

Or, here is the use of `typedef` which you should consider in this case when you need more than one pointers of same type.

```
typedef char* pchar;

pchar str, s; // both str and s are pointers
```